# Google CloudSQL Backup Options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, backups

I see that as far as automated backups go for Google CloudSQL, we only have the following options:

- Full backup once per day
- If binary logs are enabled, point in time
  recovery in-between
- Backups retained for seven days

What are my options if I want to take more backups during the day, let's say take a full backup once every 6 hours, cycle logs, retain backups for 3 months.

Is that possible?

It doesn't look to be based on the native console, i.e. there is no option there to tailor make a backup strategy like there is for example in Mongo Cloud Manager, which allows for really excellent granularity of backup sets.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL Second Generation allows ["on demand" backups](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups#when_backups_are_created). You can trigger these whenever you want, by API. They are kept until you delete them.

Comment: How do they work alongside bin logs for point in time recovery though?

Comment: Point in time recovery works by creating a new instance from a backup, and then replaying the binary log from the current instance over that new instance. Binary logs are [kept as long as the oldest backup](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/tips#bin-log-impact) so you should be able to restore to any time from your oldest backup to the present (although it could be slow).

Comment: Binary logs are purged when the oldest backup is deleted. When that happens, binary logs from before the time of the next oldest get deleted. This ensure there is always binary logs stretching back to the oldest backup, which means you can pitr from any time after the oldest oldest backup was taken.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure that this works for manual backups, it might only be considering the 7 days of *automatic* backups (otherwise a single old backup can cause your binary log to grow forever).  You might like to test to be certain.